# Why are the headers skipped in net/http?

Tags: ruby

If I do the following then the headers are skipped

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'ap'

uri = URI("https://test:A234567@www.example.com/data")

http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
request['X-appname'] = 'testapp'
request['X-token'] = '1854fac3'

response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
ap response.body
```

I get the exact same error if I comment the header lines, so that is why I say they are skipped.

The error is

```
"<Fault xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none\">
<Code><Value>Receiver</Value><Subcode><Value>NotAuthorized</Value>
</Subcode></Code><Reason><Text xml:lang=\"en-US\">Wrong username or
password.</Text></Reason></Fault>"
```

If I in Bash do

```
curl -H 'X-appname: testapp' -H 'X-token: 1854fac3'  https://test:A234567@www.example.com/data
```

then it works.

**Question**

Can anyone see why it doesn't wotk in by Ruby script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the URL requires [HTTP Basic Auth](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication).  The error in your case is with respect to user/password - `Wrong username or password.`, and not related to missing headers

You should have something like this in your code:

```
request.basic_auth 'test', 'A234567'
```

and URI should be

```
uri = URI("https://www.example.com/data")
```

Comment: It worked =) Why do I actually need to call `Net::HTTP` twice? why can't I use the `http` object to set the uri?

Comment: Not sure, that's how the API is designed I guess